# How can I not use argument to pass values between methods of different classes

Tags: java, thread-local

In general, value passing between different classes is done with argument of method, For example, passing id value like this:

```
public class Controller {
    private Service service = new Service();
    void controllerMethod() {
        Integer id = 5;
        service.serviceMethod(id);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller c = new Controller();
        c.controllerMethod();
    }
}

public class Service {
    private Dao dao = new Dao();
    void serviceMethod(Integer id) {
        dao.daoMethod(id);
    }
}

public class Dao {
    void daoMethod(Integer id) {
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}
```

These method calls are actually in a single thread, there are all in "main" thread. So I wonder if I can store this value in class 'Controller' in ThreadLocal and then get it from ThreadLocal in class 'Dao', but I failed.

```
public class Controller {
    private Service service = new Service();

    void controllerMethod() {
        Integer id = 5;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // ----add code
        ThreadLocal<Integer> local = new ThreadLocal<>();
        local.set(id);
        // ----
        service.serviceMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller c = new Controller();
        c.controllerMethod();
    }
}

public class Service {
    private Dao dao = new Dao();

    void serviceMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        dao.daoMethod();
    }
}

public class Dao {
    void daoMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // ----add code
        ThreadLocal<Integer> local = new ThreadLocal<>();
        System.out.println(local.get());
        // ----
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

I don't know why...Can this method be used to achieve passing value without argument actually? I hope someone can help me.

> ps:
>   Is there any other way to implement a no-arguments transfer of values between multiple classes?

Comment: Thread local is used for making sure you have an object that is unique to the thread running it. eg. a Random in threadlocal means that each thread uses it's own instance of a Random.

Comment: You could use `public static` variables: but don't. Passing by parameter is good.

Comment: Write it in database and read it from database or use JMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ThreadLocal` is usually used as a static variable:

```
public class Main {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> CURRENT_ID = new ThreadLocal<>(1);

    private void method1() {
        CURRENT_ID.set(100);
        method2();
    }

    private void method2() {
        System.out.println("ID: " + CURRENT_ID.get());
    }
}
```

But for regular application code, you will almost never need to use `ThreadLocal` directly. Even if it makes writing the code easier, always keep *testing* in mind! So in your case, I would consider to keep passing the necessary variables as parameters.

If you considered passing dependencies like DAOs or services via ThreadLocal, you should instead consider [dependency injection](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DependencyInjection/article.html).

When having method with too many parameters, instead of passing some parameters via ThreadLocal, have a look at [parameter objects](http://wiki.c2.com/?ParameterObject).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this::

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("id", "5");
        getId();
    }
    public static void getId() {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("id"));
    }
}
```

You can set the property and can access it from anywhere.
This is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System Class of Java- Solution suggested by @Abhishek

```
System.setProperty("id", Integer.toString(5));
```

Now you can use getProperty("id") method and read the value if id in another class.

```
  System.getProperty("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

ThreadLocal class gives each thread its own instance of the specific object. It's not for passing parameters, use it when you have some object that is not thread-safe but you want to avoid synchronizing access to that object.
It depends of access type of your parameter or variables, if they are local inside an specific method and they are not constant and also the return value or the code of method body depends on that variable then make it as an input argument of that method, but if it's global on the whole class then make it a class level variable and use getter and setters to access it and if the variable of classs level is shared between all instances of that class then make it static, according of your design, scenario and requirements you may also make it final or initialize the variable in constructors or static code blocks.